# How do I call a fragment from inside a custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

DogActivity is using a custom View. The custom view handles some logic and so has fields. When a particular field reaches a certain value, I want to start a fragment whose parent is DogActivity. How would I do that?

Is it advisable to put a callback inside a custom view so that it calls its parent activity? Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When programming you should always look for consistency, i.e. look around you and see how similar stuff to what you want to do is done. The Android SDK makes heavy use of callback listeners, so they are the way to go here.

In fact we don't even need to know what kind of `View` your `CustomView` really is, we can build a general purpose solution. Don't forget to adapt/optimize according to your specific surroundings however. And think about abstraction and generalisation once you get to a point where all your `View`s are spammed with listeners!

You will need 3 things:

#### A listener interface

```
public interface OnCountReachedListener {
    public void onCountReached();
}
```

#### A place to accept the listener and a place to alert the listener in your `CustomView`

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    private int theCount;
    private OnCountReachedListener mListener;

    public void setOnCountReachedListener(OnCountReachedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        while (theCount < 100) {
            theCount++;
        }
        // The count is where we want it, alert the listener!
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onCountReached();
        }
    }
```

#### An implementation of the interface in your Activity

```
public class DogActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myView = new CustomView();
        myView.setOnCountReachedListener(new OnCountReachedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCountReached() { 
                Log.w("tag", "COUNT REACHED!");

                // START YOUR FRAGMENT TRANSACTION HERE
            }
        });
     }
}
```

For further information look at the source code of the `View` class and all the `On**XY**Listener` interfaces in the Android SDK. They should give you plenty to think about

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the field? Is it an `EditText`? `SeekBar`? Depending on the `View`, you'll be able to specify different listeners/callbacks to determine when they have changed and if they've reached a certain threshold. I would attach these listeners within `onCreate` of `DogActivity`. When the threshold is reached, use a `FragmentTransaction` to add your `Fragment` as the child of a container View in `DogActivity`.

Comment: The field is an integer.

Comment: I meant what is the class you're using to capture input, not the type of the data that's being inputted. Sounds like it's an EditText..?

Comment: I just extend View. I use the canvas of the view for a number of drawings and animations. the int field is incremented during the course of operation of the View.

Comment: I would define an interface (ie CustomViewListener) that includes methods/events you need to listen to (ie "onIntValueChanged"), then define a public method within your custom class to set the listener from your Activity (also adding the listener as a member of the custom View class). And call the appropriate method from within the view whenever a particular field has changed.